# How do I add the Postgis distance to the result set

Tags: postgresql, postgis

Here’s my current query which currently returns the name and point of eligible results ordered by distance, how can I include the distance as well in the result set?

Query:

```
select name, ST_AsText(location) from places where ST_DWithin(
    ST_GeogFromText('SRID=4326;POINT($point)'),
    location,
    $distance
) ORDER BY ST_Distance(
    ST_GeogFromText('SRID=4326;POINT($point)'),
    location
)
```

`$distance` and `$point` will need to be guarded against sql injection in due course obviously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT name,
       ST_AsText(location),
       ST_Distance(ST_GeogFromText('SRID=4326;POINT($point)'),location)
FROM places
WHERE ST_DWithin(ST_GeogFromText('SRID=4326;POINT($point)'), location, $distance)
ORDER BY ST_Distance( ST_GeogFromText('SRID=4326;POINT($point)'), location);
```

However, for your query to work location should also be casted to a geography (if it is not).